# Converting map coordinates using AutoCad to Excel sheet

Tags: coordinates, autocad, excel

I have some maps of pieces of lands and I want to convert the coordinates to excel sheet

I want to arrange the data like this in the excel sheet:

land number( the pink number in the pic)  accompanied by its coordinates  in each row

Can you help me?

[image]

[link to the map file above:](http://www.mediafire.com/?y3foq3yydhdppfb)

I want to have 3 columns in the Excel sheet

1. representing the land number text value
2. representing the the coordinates of that land separated by "_" like this
   `23.87718162405882_57.10554858573619_23.877357092058385_57.105595188322354_23.877292855536815_57.10588146117277` each two representing a point/corner
3. the block number where the land is

if the format of the coordinates can not be like above then there is no harm having 3 columns x and y or easting and northing plus point number. therefore each land will have rows of the same points number

Answer (score 4):

You can use the query to report, or the export functions.

[image: report query]